# why is the set of intersections and symmetric differences of a fixed set finite

Tags: boolean-algebra, finite-rings, boolean-ring

I have a question very similar to [Finite ring of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391619/finite-ring-of-sets)

For a given set U, the set R of subsets is a ring under the operations of symmetric difference ($\bigtriangleup$) and intersection ($\cap$).

Given a finite set V of subsets of U, the set W generated by V is a subring of R.   I.e., W is the set with the following two properties:

1) $V \subset W$

2) If $a \in W$ and $b \in W$, then $a \cap b \in W$ and $a \bigtriangleup b \in W$.

My question is:   Why is W finite?

This is clear when I draw a picture.  If I start with a fixed set of subsets of U, and start drawing intersections and symmetric differences, and keep enlarging the set by the results, I eventually exhaust all the possibilities.

Clearly this is not true for general rings generated by a finite set.  For example, given the finite set $\{1,-1\} \subset Z$, the generated set is all the integers.

One way to argue this is with a VERY BIG HAMMER which I'd like to avoid.

Assume we have two boolean expressions in Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF),  I can express the intersection and symmetric differences of the two expressions also in DNF.  And there is only a finite number, $2^{2^N}$, of possible DNFs of N variables.

I hope there's a simpler way to argue this other than resorting to DNF representations.

Answer (score 1):

There are only finitely many sets that are intersections of sets in $V$ and their complements. Every set in $W$ must be a union of those.

(This straightforward argument may be just a rephrasing of the idea behind the BIG HAMMER you want to avoid.)

Edit in response to comment from the OP

> Not doubting of course, but not understanding the reasoning.

Here's another kind of argument. Maybe it helps your intuition.

Each subset of $U$ is completely described by its characteristic function. The ring structure on subsets is isomorphic to the ring structure of the characteristic functions with pointwise operations mod $2$.

You are interested in a finitely generated subring of that ring. The finite number of characteristic functions $\chi_a$ and  $1 - \chi_a$ for $a \in V$ can be distinguished by their values at a finite subset of $U$, so that will be true of the functions in the subring they generate.

This is a more formal way to say that the universe $U$ might as well be finite - in which case the question is trivial.

Comment: Why must every set in W be a union of intersections of sets in V and their complements?  And yes, this indeed seems like a claim that every element of W has a unique DNF.

Comment: @JimNewton Because any calculation of an intersection or symmetric difference that starts with sets of that kind results in a set of that kind. I guess that's formally a structural induction, but I find it a convincing informal argument.

Comment: Hi Ethan,  There is still something I'm missing.  Not doubting of course, but not understanding the reasoning.

Let R be a ring, and $V \subset R$ be finite.
Define set W as the smallest set obeying the following two properties

1) $V \subset W$

2) If $a \in W$ and $b \in W$, then $a+b \in W$ and $a \cdot b \in W$

It is not true in general that W is therefore finite.  But in the case of the ring of subsets, W is finite.   Perhaps it stems from the fact that $A \cap A = A$ and $A \bigtriangleup A = \emptyset$?

Comment: OK, I don't exactly know what characteristic functions on rings are.  So I guess I need to go and research that.    

BTW, Ethan, thanks for the help.  I'm working on an article wherein this is something I need to claim/prove/cite before going on to my actual thesis.  If you send me your credentials, I'll be happy to site you in the article.

Comment: The characteristic function of a _set_ is the function that's $1$ on the set and $0$ elsewhere. I think if you said your ring of sets  is obviously finite no one would object. You can find my contact on my SE profile, but I don't need thanks in the article.